# Is there a better way to modify a function being constantly called by many threads?

Tags: c++, windows, synchronization, hook, atomic

I am trying to hook a function that is usually being called by multiple threads without any idle time in between. I was wondering what's the safest way to hook the function, preventing other threads (which I do  not own) to not execute the code while I am hooking the function.

My initial idea was to suspend the other threads, but this is not ideal in my situation. I decided to use atomic operations. This is some pseudocode I have come up with to test my idea:

```
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>
#include <Windows.h>

void hook()
{
    puts("Function hooked");
}

void func()
{
    puts("Actual function");
}

void __declspec(noreturn) thread()
{
    while (true)
        func(); //Hammer the function
}

int main()
{
    DWORD old;
    VirtualProtect(func, 0x5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &old); //change memory protections so we can write

    //create the threads and release the handle (we don't own them)
    std::thread t{thread};
    t.detach();

    std::thread s{thread};
    s.detach();

    std::thread z{thread};
    z.detach();

    //sleep 1 second to allow `threads t, s, z` to run
    Sleep(1000);

    //Hook the function
    _InterlockedExchange8(reinterpret_cast<char*>(func), 0xe9);
    const auto diff = static_cast<ULONG>(reinterpret_cast<ULONG>(hook) - reinterpret_cast<ULONG>(func)) - 5;
    _InterlockedExchange(reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(reinterpret_cast<PUCHAR>(func) + 1), diff);

    //Halt the current thread until program is terminated
    WaitForSingleObject(GetCurrentProcess(), INFINITE);
}
```

**This works, but is it safe?** Or is it working only because of the time it takes to call `puts` and return? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The only reason I call `Sleep(1000)` is to simulate a situation where I hook the function while the threads are in full swing. (If I hook right after creating the threads, the threads may not have been scheduled to run yet, defeating the purpose.) @Frank

Comment: This is very tricky to answer because as far as the language is concerned, there's a ton of Undefined Behavior involved here. My gut tells me that this will be extremely cache dependant since I don't think the CPU fetching an instruction qualifies as an acquire.

Comment: _This works, but is it safe?_ No, because there is a race condition between patching in the `jmp` instruction (e9) and then the address of `hook`.  In fact, I can't think of a safe way of doing this if other threads might call `func` while you are attempting to patch it.  Even suspending those threads won't help as they might be executing the entry code to `func` when you suspend them.

Comment: I'm not confident enough to make it an answer, but I believe that you can use `WriteProcessMemory()` to make this somewhat safer, at least from a cache standpoint.

Comment: this not safe anyway. even if you interlocked swap code bytes - not safe because another thread can at this point execute instructions which you try replace. if want be safe - need suspend all threads in process, except self, check context of all threads, check  - are eip(rip) not inside code which you try swap. if yes (not inside) - swap bytes, and resume threads

Comment: @RbMm Yeah, after reading the comments and answers I started to get a stronger feeling of using `NtSuspendThread` and `NtGetContextThread` to check, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon a number of factors, and there are a number of possible solutions.

1. Can the function be written so that it is reentrant? That is, can you make the function such that it doesn't matter if multiple threads are using it simultaneously? The lack of static variables (static constants are ok) and the lack of calls to non-reentrant routines would make it non-reentrant itself. In that case, no synchronization is necessary.
2. It looks like you are writing the code for the function yourself. Why not just put a static mutex in the function and lock it while you are executing code that violates the reentrant criteria? The critical section might be a very small portion of the whole function, and the thread suspension brief.
3. It looks like you are writing the code for the other threads. You could share a global mutex that each thread locks when it calls the function.
4. If the other threads are in separate processes, you should look into the [Interprocess Synchronization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/interprocess-synchronization) capabilities in Windows. This would allow you to produce a [system mutex object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects) and give it to all the processes for their use to allow synchronized access to the function.

Note that solutions 2, 3 and 4 do suspend the threads, so may not be acceptable in your situation.

Also, note that you detach the threads, but the function is part of your code. Will the threads continue running after your code exits? Those detached threads will then be calling deleted code.

Comment: I tried to make my code a "hypothetical" scenario. For the real scenario, the threads are not owned or written by me. All I have is the thread's ID. The thread is in another process. And yes, the threads will continue to run after my code exits.

Comment: I'm confused, then. Who controls the function? Is it a system function or one written by you? How do you know when those other threads are calling the function? If you have no control over the threads but control over the function, you're either going to have to do some gatekeeping at the site of the function call (e.g., mutex), or rewrite things to allow reentrancy (the best solution, though it may require rethinking how the function works).

Comment: This is a system function. I have no idea when the threads are calling the function. But yeah, I was fearing that I would have to apply some control flow checking at the beginning of the function.

Comment: I'm going to add information about interprocess synchronization (sharing a mutex across processes). That may address your problem safely.